# Has web3.eth.getAccounts() changed in metamask?

Tags: web3js, metamask

Has `web3.eth.getAccounts()` behavior changen when using MetaMask?  I remember it used to return a full list of available accounts, but now it looks like it only returns array of length 1 - the current selected account.

Answer (score 1):

It's returned an array of length 1 for over a year, I can't remember when it ever returned more.

- A MetaMask Developer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you changed the provider?
See this: https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/issues/54